# WooCommerce skip step checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How skip step payment in checkout ? 
I need 2 step.
1. inputs first name and last name, full adress, number phone from user
2. Submit order

Comment: Please cehck this link it might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729643/removing-payment-gateways-from-woocommerce

Comment: thank ! How create print order page?