# How can I create a Woocommerce site which 'sells' free items and only asks for name and e-mail on checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm making a WordPress site for a client which will be on a subdomain of their main URL. They will give the URL to members of the press, who can browse (watermarked) images, add them to their cart, and checkout, giving only their e-mail address, name and who they write for. They then receive a zip with their files in.

I thought Woocommerce would be great for this, as it allows my client to add new images and remove older ones, and they will receive an e-mail every time someone has downloaded an image, which is part of the brief.

The only problem I can foresee with this is that the user will have to input payment details on checkout, which my client won't accept.

Can anyone think of a good solution for this please? Very much appreciated.

Comment: See the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16731926/3739498. If you use COD and change the title, you won't have to do payment info.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much! Looks like that'll do the job perfectly.